# What is the name of this Facebook functionality?

Tags: facebook

I have been seeing a few sites which have a Facebook box (very like the likebox) which shows, when I'm logged into Facebook, those of my friends who use the website or the website application.

I can't find any documentation about this box (like http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/). Does anyone know what the name of it is, and where I can find documentation about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the name is [Facepile](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/).